# Change the Cell color on postrender using JSlink

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jslink

I am using JSlink to change the cell color of a calculated column. I have to use `Postrendering` for that. The problem is that I cannot manipulate the cells.

I can color the rows but cannot color just one cell. As long as I am not using the view, don't know how to change the background color of just one cell. I have tried to use `dRate.columnname`, but it does not work. 
Here is my function for changing the whole row color:

```
function ColourDv(ctx) {

   for(var i=0; i < ctx.ListData.Row.length; i++)
   {
       var listItem = ctx.ListData.Row[i];
       var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, listItem);
       var row = document.getElementById(iid);


        var dRate = listItem.Delivery_x0020_Rate;
        var nRate=dRate.replace('%','').replace(',','');

        if (nRate < 900)

        row.style.backgroundColor = "#d67763";

    else if( nRate < 950 )

    row.style.backgroundColor = "#f6ab3f";

    else 

        row.style.backgroundColor = "#8cba3f";
        }
           }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code as your OnPostRender function:

```
function ColourDv(ctx) {
    var header = document.querySelector("[name=Delivery_x0020_Rate]").parentNode;
    var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < ctx.ListData.Row.length; i++) {
        var listItem = ctx.ListData.Row[i];
        var iid = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, listItem);
        var row = document.getElementById(iid);
        var dRate = listItem.Delivery_x0020_Rate;
        var nRate = dRate.replace('%', '').replace(',', '');
        var cell = row.querySelector("td:nth-child(" + index + ")")
        if (nRate < 900) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "#d67763";
        } else if (nRate < 950) {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "#f6ab3f";
        } else {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = "#8cba3f";
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

The changes are pretty simple.

First we get the index of your Delivery Rate column:

```
var header = document.querySelector("[name=Delivery_x0020_Rate]").parentNode;
var index = [].slice.call(header.parentNode.children).indexOf(header) + 1;
```

And then, instead of addressing the whole row, we only address the `<TD>` at this specific index:

```
var cell = row.querySelector("td:nth-child(" + index + ")")
if (nRate < 900) {
    cell.style.backgroundColor = "#d67763";
} 
...
```

Comment: Perfeeeect :) it works