# Change the background colour of a cell - not highlighting text

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, list-view, formatting

I'm using the script editor to format my list. When I use this block of code:

```
function boldTemplate(ctx){
    var value = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    switch(value){
        case "":
            return"<span style='background-color:yellow'>"+"testing"+"</span>";
            break;
    }
}
```

This will highlight the text "testing" instead of making the whole cell yellow.

If my switch case looked like this:

```
switch(value){
    case "":
        return"<span style='background-color:yellow'>"+"</span>";
        break;
}
```

No colour would be displayed at all.

Is there a way to colour the cells?

Answer (score 1):

Span is an in-line element. Change it to a div or update the style of the span to display as block.
Ex:

```
<span style=‘display:block;width:100%;background-color:yellow’>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the height 100% too? I tried to add `height:100%` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: it seems like adding `height:50px` works, but I don't want the height to be a fixed size

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behavior, you are trying the pass the style to the **content** of `SPAN` and when the `SPAN` is empty it doesn't show anything!

So try to use `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` for the **empty** SPAN! or use `DIV` instead with `block` style!

If you need to fill the list item cell itself, so try the **JSLink** examples at

- [Change the Cell color on postrender using JSlink](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193266/change-the-cell-color-on-postrender-using-jslink)
- [Need help changing cell background color based on the content of the cell using CSR](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235575/need-help-changing-cell-background-color-based-on-the-content-of-the-cell-using)

Comment: In the examples you linked, it shows that the cell is colored from end to end but not top to bottom. Is there a way to accomplish this too?